# Tests UJS Rails with Capybara, Selenium and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, capybara, ujs

On my page I have :

-->a form that scrapes the content of another website with a Ajax request made with ujs (**remote: true**):

```
<%= simple_form_for @listing, :url => listings_fetch_url, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :url %>
  <%= f.button :submit, id: 'import_button' %>
<% end %>
```

-->another form that is populated by the scraping results from the form above

Manually it works...

However when I'm trying to *automatically test it*, it doesn't.
Capybara finds the submit button, clicks on it but then it leaves me on a  blank page.

Here is the code for the **test**:

```
feature "Listing import" do
  scenario "fills in the form fields", js: true do
    visit new_search_path
    fill_in 'Url', :with => 'www.google.fr'

    find('input#import_button').click

    expect(page.body).to have_content 'query was'
  end
end
```

The **controller actions** are the following:

```
def fetch
    url = listing_params[:url] 
    @query = Query.new(ScraperService.new({url: url}).perform)
    render :fill
end

# Renders an js.erb file
def fill
end
```

It seems like rspec with selenium can't render js.erb files?

Any help is appreciated!

## EDIT

Thanks to @ThomasWalpole, I fixed an error 500 which was preventing Mechanize to scrape the web. The content is now scraped correctly but the problem remains: the page after clicking on the submit button becomes blank and the tests ends right afer.
In the logs I have a lengthy message :

> Could not log "render_template.action_view" event. NoMethodError:
>   undefined method `example_group' for nil:NilClass
>   ["/Users/Greg/.rbenv/versions/2.4.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.6.0/lib/rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:67:in`
>   current_example_group'"

Which seems to be the same problem as : [1](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1800) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983466/controller-test-emits-debug-failure-messages-after-rails-5-1-upgrade)

Comment: Capybara with Selenium can definitely render js.erb files.  Look in your test.log file and see what requests are being made, what format they are requesting and what the response codes are.   Does any of `Query.new(ScraperService.new({url: url}).perform`  make another request to the app, run in separate threads, etc?  If so are you using :puma as your Capybara server (Capybara.server = :puma) ?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ThomasWalpole! The log revealed a 500 server error which was caused by `require 'webmock/rspec'` which was preventing Mechanize from accessing the web.
`Query.new...` isn't making another request to the app and doesn't run in a separate thread. Using Puma didn't change anything sadly.
See my updated question please.

Comment: Try downgrading to rspec 3.5.x . -- might be a bug in 3.6

Comment: Downgrading to rspec 3.5.x removed the lengthy error in the logs!

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

The problem came from the fact that my js.erb **wasn't adding a new element** on the current page (i.e.: a new class, a new id, a new DOM element...).

Capybara never waited for the Ajax request to complete!

I appended a new line to my js.erb:

```
$("#import_button").addClass("imported");
```

This way I know that when the class imported is present on the current page it means the Ajax request is over.

Then in my test I added the following line:

```
expect(page).to have_selector :css, '#import_button.imported', wait: 10
```

Everything works fine now

P.S.: [this website](https://blog.tomoyukikashiro.me/post/things-to-be-aware-of-when-change-capybara_default_wait_time/) helped me understand the problem as well