# Controller test emits debug (failure) messages after Rails 5.1 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I have recently upgraded a project to Rails 5.1.

- All deprecation warnings were fixed.
- All tests pass (I use `rspec-rails`)
- Controller tests that **call mailers using ActiveJob** are now rendering lengthy warning messages.

> [ActiveJob] [ActionMailer::DeliveryJob] [6d2ec032-eff2-40d3-bad4-3b23de65d9bd]
>   Could not log "render_template.action_view" event. NoMethodError: undefined method 'example_group' for nil:NilClass 
>   [
>
> "rails/view_rendering.rb:67:in 'current_example_group'",
>     "rspec/rails/view_rendering.rb:71:in 'render_template'",
>     "active_support/subscriber.rb:99:in 'finish'",
>
> ... LIST SHORTENED FOR CLARITY ...
>
> "active_job/execution.rb:20:in 'execute'",
>
> ... LIST SHORTENED ...
>
> "concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:319:in 'block in create_worker'"
>   ]

What has changed in Rails 5.1 for testing (API) controllers that send emails? Am I doing something wrong?

```
describe Api::UsersController do
    it 'creates a new user' do
      # THIS ENDPOINT CALLS
      #   UserMailer.welcome_email(user).deliver_later
      post :create, params: params
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is a known issue https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1800

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and was using `rspec-rails 3.6.0`. I've downgraded back to `3.5.0` which fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Hmm, any better solution to this?